# Creating a filled contour plot from a cvs (x,y,c) matrix

Tags: r, contour

I am trying to use R for this task -- creating a filled contour plot from a csv file, a (x,y,c) matrix. I got my measurements from a football field - x and y indicate the location in the field, ranging from 1 to 11. c is the measurement.

Here is the data looks:

```
,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
2,0,0,0,0.4,0.6,0.6,0.6,0.4,0,0,0
3,0,0,0.5,0.7,0.8,0.8,0.8,0.7,0.5,0,0
4,0,0.4,0.7,0.8,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.8,0.7,0.4,0
5,0,0.6,0.8,0.9,1.0,1.0,1.0,0.9,0.8,0.6,0
6,0,0.6,0.8,0.9,1.0,1.0,1.0,0.9,0.8,0.6,0
7,0,0.6,0.8,0.9,1.0,1.0,1.0,0.9,0.8,0.6,0
8,0,0.4,0.7,0.8,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.8,0.7,0.4,0
9,0,0,0.5,0.7,0.8,0.8,0.8,0.7,0.5,0,0
10,0,0,0,0.4,0.6,0.6,0.6,0.4,0,0,0
11,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

Please provide an example to plot a filled contour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
z <- as.matrix(read.csv(text=',1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11\n1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0\n2,0,0,0,0.4,0.6,0.6,0.6,0.4,0,0,0\n3,0,0,0.5,0.7,0.8,0.8,0.8,0.7,0.5,0,0\n4,0,0.4,0.7,0.8,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.8,0.7,0.4,0\n5,0,0.6,0.8,0.9,1.0,1.0,1.0,0.9,0.8,0.6,0\n6,0,0.6,0.8,0.9,1.0,1.0,1.0,0.9,0.8,0.6,0\n7,0,0.6,0.8,0.9,1.0,1.0,1.0,0.9,0.8,0.6,0\n8,0,0.4,0.7,0.8,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.8,0.7,0.4,0\n9,0,0,0.5,0.7,0.8,0.8,0.8,0.7,0.5,0,0\n10,0,0,0,0.4,0.6,0.6,0.6,0.4,0,0,0\n11,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0\n',row.names=1));
z;
##    X1  X2  X3  X4  X5  X6  X7  X8  X9 X10 X11
## 1   0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0   0
## 2   0 0.0 0.0 0.4 0.6 0.6 0.6 0.4 0.0 0.0   0
## 3   0 0.0 0.5 0.7 0.8 0.8 0.8 0.7 0.5 0.0   0
## 4   0 0.4 0.7 0.8 0.9 0.9 0.9 0.8 0.7 0.4   0
## 5   0 0.6 0.8 0.9 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.9 0.8 0.6   0
## 6   0 0.6 0.8 0.9 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.9 0.8 0.6   0
## 7   0 0.6 0.8 0.9 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.9 0.8 0.6   0
## 8   0 0.4 0.7 0.8 0.9 0.9 0.9 0.8 0.7 0.4   0
## 9   0 0.0 0.5 0.7 0.8 0.8 0.8 0.7 0.5 0.0   0
## 10  0 0.0 0.0 0.4 0.6 0.6 0.6 0.4 0.0 0.0   0
## 11  0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0   0
filled.contour(z,color.palette=terrain.colors);
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thank you! Good example for me to start. Do you know how to reverse the (x,y) start from upper left corner??

Comment: The figure needs to be turn clockwise by 90 degree to match the actual location in the dataset.